# string parent node xml parse with jaxb java

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

How to parse xml having parent node name as string in jaxb. I am trying to parse my xml string by binding into a model class using JAXB. My xml string looks something like this:

```
String inputXml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
            + "<string xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"
            + " <Response Code=\"1212\">\n"
            + "     <Message>Operation is succesfully completed</Message>\n"
            + " </Response>\n"
            + "</string>";
```

**My question is how can I create a model class to map this xml into it?** If I remove the string parent node like this:

```
String inputXml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
            + " <Response Code=\"1212\">\n"
            + "     <Message>Operation is succesfully completed</Message>\n"
            + " </Response>\n";
```

I can create a model class as:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Response")
public class Response {

String Code;
String Message;
public String getCode() {
    return Code;
}

@XmlAttribute(name = "Code")
public void setCode(String Code) {
    this.Code= Code;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return Message;
}

@XmlElement(name = "Message")
public void setMessage(String Message) {
    this.Message = Message;
}    

@Override
public String toString() {
    return Message;
}
}
```

And in my java class I can parse using JAXB as:

```
    InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new StringReader(inputXml));

    // map xml to model class in jaxb
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Response.class);
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    Response response = (Response) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(inputSource);
```

But I have to parse with xml that have

> < string xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">...< /string>

as parent node. I even tried to follow this answer: 
[How to parse/unmarshall the string xml inside a string xml into a Java object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19993327/how-to-parse-unmarshall-the-string-xml-inside-a-string-xml-into-a-java-object)

but not working. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the content in a StringReader,

```
StringReader reader = new StringReader(inputXml);
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Response.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
Response response = (Response) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
```